# How to configure ipv6 in kamailio

Tags: kamailio

I want to configure the kamailio to run in IPV6 .

I saw in kamailio.cfg we need to assign the ip adderss like below

```
#!substdef "!DBURL!mysql:///etc/kamailio/db.mysql!g"
#!substdef "!MY_IP_ADDR!192.168.1.119!g"
#!substdef "!MY_DOMAIN!example.com!g"
#!substdef "!MY_WS_PORT!4442!g"
#!substdef "!MY_WSS_PORT!4443!g"
#!substdef "!MY_MSRP_PORT!4444!g"
#!substdef "!MY_WS_ADDR!tcp:MY_IP_ADDR:MY_WS_PORT!g"
#!substdef "!MY_WSS_ADDR!tls:MY_IP_ADDR:MY_WSS_PORT!g"
#!substdef "!MY_MSRP_ADDR!tls:MY_IP_ADDR:MY_MSRP_PORT!g"
#!substdef "!MSRP_MIN_EXPIRES!1800!g"
#!substdef "!MSRP_MAX_EXPIRES!3600!g
```

Here I put ipv4 ip address and it is working fine,

When I replace it to IPV6 it is not working!

Any suggestion how to configure it for IPV6 will great help for me.

Answer (score 1):

default kamailio configuration supports ipv6 if it has interface [link](https://github.com/kamailio/kamailio/blob/master/etc/kamailio.cfg)

In addition;
it can be configured listening ip address by [listen parameter](https://www.kamailio.org/wiki/cookbooks/5.2.x/core#listen)
For example

```
listen=udp:[2a02:1850:1:1::13]:5060

auto_bind_ipv6=1
dns_try_ipv6=yes
```

if your configuration is complex to unable to choose interface , [force_send_socket](https://www.kamailio.org/wiki/cookbooks/5.2.x/core#force_send_socket) function helps